# Retrieving strings from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have here

```
  <table align="center">
  <tr>
     <td>ID No</td><td>:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="idno" size="10px" maxlength="15px" ></td>
     <td><input type="submit" value="Search ID No." name="search"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $sql="select * from stud where ID_No='$_POST[idno]';";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $s=mysql_fetch_array($result);

     $addr = $s[Home_addr];
     echo"$addr";
   ?>
```

How to get the whole address?

This script only returns the first word from the database.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be a CakePHP question. !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the data:

```php
<?php
include('connect.php');
$idno = (integer) $_POST['idno'];
$sql="select * from stud where ID_No='$idno';";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($s=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $addr = $s['Home_addr'];
    echo "$addr";
}
?>
```

Also, please don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000289/create-mysql-table-with-php-variable-not-working#13000306) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: actually i was also using that code.. instead of displaying "San Pedro" it will display only "San".. the "Pedro" won't display.. how would I do this.. can you help me?? please :).. actually i'm a beginner.. i'm very thankful that you respond to my question..

Answer (score 1):

Iterate for `mysql_fetch_array`

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $sql="select * from stud where ID_No='$_POST[idno]';";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($s=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

     $addr = $s[Home_addr];
     echo"$addr";
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Not necessary for single-row results. id_no suggests it'd be a PK field.

Comment: hello.. thank you for answering the question.. i would like to add how to display "San Pedro" from the database.. actually I was also using this code but this would only display "San".. the "pedro" would not display.. can you help me with this?? thank you for the respond..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, off topic. But please do not put user input from the $_POST array directly into a query. You need to pass it through mysql_real_escape_string() first or else you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Also, the keys of your associative arrays are strings so please quote them:

```
$s['Home_addr']
```

not

```
$s[Home_addr]
```

in the latter, PHP will first attempt to treat Home_addr as a constant but when it's not found it will fall back on treating it like a string so it does work but it's not reliable, probably slower, and simply wrong.