# Create mysql table with php variable not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to php.. and this is probably a stupid mistake... but I have no idea what is going on. I'm trying to create a table in my database using php. I want to name the table after the username. I'm using the variable `$tableusername`. Here's my code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $tableusername = $row["username"];
        }

$create = "CREATE TABLE `".$tableusername."` ('
    . ' `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, '
    . ' `please` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, '
    . ' `make` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, '
    . ' `this` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, '
    . ' `work` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL'
    . ' )'
    . ' ENGINE = myisam;";

mysql_query($create)


?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
You have successfully signed up. <?php echo $tableusername ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So- This creates a table named `$tableusername`. The variable doesn't carry over. BUT- when I `echo $tableusername` - the variable carries over. I'm pretty new to this - so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: `$username` and `$tableusername` are the same according to your code :)

Comment: Why create a table for every user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your SQL querys - (It really helps and speeds up error correcting time)

```
or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```

**echos** this in your instance:

A MySQL error has occurred.
Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' . ' `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ' . ' `please` VARCH' at line 1

This then indicates to me that the error regards **"** & **'**.

---

After changing the code to contain single quotes and executing it, there is now no echo.

```
   <?php
    $tableusername = "philip";
    $create = "CREATE TABLE `".$tableusername."` ("
        . " `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
        . " `please` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
        . " `make` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
        . " `this` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
        . " `work` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL"
        . " )"
        . " ENGINE = myisam;";

    mysql_query($create)or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());

    ?>
```

---

Note: Please refer to the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension when using SQL embedded in PHP. mysql_* is in a deprecation process.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have invalid concatenation of string, use `double quotes` instead of `single quotes`.

```
$create = "CREATE TABLE `".$tableusername."` ("
    . " `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
    . " `please` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
    . " `make` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
    . " `this` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "
    . " `work` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL' "
    . " )"
    . " ENGINE = myisam;";
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are saying to use double quotes instead of single quotes, rather than just ensuring that they match?

Comment: @WaleedKhan look at the code in the question above, the single quotes are included inside the string.

Comment: I mean to say that it would work equally well if single-quotes were used rather than double-quotes. I'm just wondering why you choose one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

// Create MySql table with variable

```
$tableName = "tb-"."$userEmail";
$tName="Beta";  
$createTable = "CREATE TABLE ".$tName." ( UserName varchar(30), UserPassword varchar(30) )" ;
```

This above syntax works. Apply this example to your code.
Please review some error in your concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$create = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE `$tableusername` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `please` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `make` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `this` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `work` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = myisam;
SQL;
```

Notably, you can use string interpolation in a heredoc, but you should really tend toward parametrized queries.