# Php and Mysql no table added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am new to php and mysql. i am now having online tutorials for this topic. i use wamp and already created various databases without tables in it yet. now i created a file createTable.php with these line of codes:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE example(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(id),
name VARCHAR(30), 
age INT)")
 or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";
?>
```

in this code i create a table named example. now when i check inside phpmyAdmin in wamp the example table is not added on the test database. what's the problem with my code? or is it the WAMP?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See
 the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: and use either [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000289/create-mysql-table-with-php-variable-not-working#13000306) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)

Comment: Also post any error messages, and ensure that your SQL works in MySQL console.

Comment: @NullPointer is totally right... First please check that your DB connection is effectively made.

Comment: thank you all for the fast response..ill try using mySQLi..

Comment: @ClydeWinux try the pdo instead the mysqli its more simple functional

Comment: i have another question.. can i just create batabase through coding the same way as when i create the table? if not is WAMP the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and see its running, just make some changes it it.
while you using wamp then try this code.

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
    mysql_select_db("test"); 
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE example( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHAR(30),  age INT)");    
    echo "Table Created!"; 
?>
```

Comment: thanks so much this code works.. :-)
should i use mysql or mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE 'example'(
'id'    INT   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
'name'  VARCHAR(30), 
'age'   INT,
 PRIMARY KEY('id'))
  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

echo "Table Created!";